# Node-red tcp bytes being dropped

Tags: tcp, node-red, binary-data

I'm trying to send 20480 bytes (5120 int32s) every 100ms via tcp request node to my python socket server running on localhost.

Somehow my server is only receiving bytes at ~1/10th this rate. I haven't worked with binary data in JS before, and never used node red, so likely I'm doing something wrong.

I added a debug node to confirm msg.payload.length is 20480 and approx ten messages per second are generated.

From my function node:

```
var abuff = new ArrayBuffer(5120*4)
var tmpArr = new Int32Array(abuff);
for (var i=0;i<5120;i++)
{
//fill tmpArr
}

msg.payload=Buffer.from(abuff)

return msg;
```

I've inspected some of the bytes from the Python side and they appear correct there's just not enough of them.

Why is my data rate incorrect?

Comment: Have you checked the Node-RED process? is it running at 100% of a single core?

Comment: @hardillb In Resource Monitor (windows) I see all 8 of my cores jump to around 40-70% but none of them are pegged to 100%

Comment: It's important to remember that any nodejs application will only ever use 1 core

Comment: Understood. I'm not sure what to tell you but when I run this I consistently see increases in all my cores, none of them reach 100% however. I maybe should have noted, in case it's relevant, this is the STM32CubeMonitor app which I think wraps Node Red.